# Check if any combination of columns are equal some specific value in matrix

Tags: r

I would like to get all combinations of columns which have specific value together for example 1,1,1,1 in matrix in R language.

We using only 0 and 1 . Like for true and false

So for example from this code which is below would be column 2 and 6 which create 1,1,1,1

Some code:

```r
A <- matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1),4,6)
A

print("Combination of expected result ")

B <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1),4,1)
B
```

expected result i would like to achieve is for this example 2 , 6 which means column 2 and 6 together can combine 1,1,1,1

Comment: There is no code in your Some code...

Comment: what is the `specific value together of two columns`? Do you mean the sum of two columns?

Comment: Yes exactly , can be even sum of more.than two

Comment: Columns 2 and 6 add up to `2,1,1,1`

Comment: We using only 0 and 1 . Like for true and false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a combination of all the columns taken 2 at a time, subset them from `A` and compare it with `B` if all the values are same we return that column index or return `NA`.

```
out <- combn(seq(ncol(A)), 2, function(x) 
          if(all(pmax(A[, x[1]], A[, x[2]]) == B)) toString(x) else NA, )
out[!is.na(out)]
#[1] "2, 6"
```

Currently, the output returns a comma-separated string, based on how you want your final output, you can change this. Maybe use `simplify = FALSE` to get a list.

Answer (score 2):

It looks a bit congested (using `combn()` twice) but does the job.

```
i1 <- combn(seq(6), 2, FUN = function(i)rowSums(A[,i]) > 0)
combn(seq(6), 2)[,colSums(i1) == nrow(i1)]
#[1] 2 6
```

Comment: expected result i would like to achieve is for this example 2 , 6 which means column 2 and 6 together can combine 1,1,1,1

Comment: How do you want your output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you achieve all combinations of columns (choose any number of columns, i.e., from `1` to `ncol(A)`) that meet your objective, you can use the following solution:

```
r <- Filter(nchar,unlist(sapply(seq(ncol(A)), function(k) combn(seq(ncol(A)),k, function(x) ifelse(all(as.numeric(rowSums(as.matrix(A[,x]))>=1)==B), toString(x), NA)))))
```

then you will get

```
> r
 [1] "2, 6"             "1, 2, 6"          "2, 3, 6"          "2, 4, 6"          "2, 5, 6"          "1, 2, 3, 6"       "1, 2, 4, 6"       "1, 2, 5, 6"       "2, 3, 4, 6"      
[10] "2, 3, 5, 6"       "2, 4, 5, 6"       "1, 2, 3, 4, 6"    "1, 2, 3, 5, 6"    "1, 2, 4, 5, 6"    "2, 3, 4, 5, 6"    "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
```

Hope this can do some help!